# Scrollable whitespace to right of page using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, removing-whitespace

I am getting some scrollable whitespace to the right of the page content on https://crane-tech.net

Im not sure what's causing it exactly or how I can find out without checking every line manually. Im sure it is something simple like a missing bracket, but Im not sure. Ive seen a couple others have this issue, but have not found a definitive answer. It is only on the index.html page too which is what confuses me the most because they were all built from the same template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an issue with your

```
<div class="row no-gutters px-5 my-5">
  <div class="col-10 offset-8">
    <h2 class="text-warning h5 mr-5 pr-5">
```

You could simply rename the 2nd div to `<div class="col-2 offset-8">` for a similar result.

This still leaves a few px white scroll, which is caused by `<div class="header">`

To fix this, add the following css rule:

```
.row.justify-content-center {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: That worked for the most part, but there still seems to be a bit of scrollable whitespace. Could you explain why that is happening by chance so that I know what to look for?

Comment: @CulturedICrane The website you linked does not have any whitespace to the right any more for me. Using `col-10` and `offset-8` ends in a total of 18, while Bootstrap's grid system has a max of 12. Usually it would wrap to another line, but I guess `offset-` does not count towards those 12.